# ORA-01408 Error when Setting Up Hangfire with FluentNHibernate for Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, .net-core, hangfire

I'm trying to set up Hangfire with FluentNHibernate for on Oracle database, but I'm encountering the following error:

`ORA-01408: such column list already indexed`

I have the following setup:

1. RegisterHangfire.cs

```
public static void RegisterHangfire(
            this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
            CustomSettings customSettings)
        {
            var storage = FluentNHibernateStorageFactory.For(
                ProviderTypeEnum.OracleClient10Managed,
                DATABASE_URL,
                new FluentNHibernateStorageOptions
                {
                    TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable,
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                    JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                    CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    UpdateSchema = true,
                    DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
                    InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                    TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    JobQueueDistributedLockTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0),
                    DistributedLockPollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15.0),
                    DeadlockRetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0),
                    DbmsTimeSyncInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0),
                    TablePrefix = "HANGFIRE_",
                });

            serviceCollection.AddHangfire(cfg => cfg.UseStorage(storage));

            serviceCollection.AddHangfireServer();
        }
```

2. Program.cs

```
...
builder.Services.RegisterHangfire(customSettings);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHangfireDashboard();
...
```

I've tried changing the `UpdateSchema` property. It's strange that if I run with `true` the tables are created but the app throws an error:  "ORA-01408: such column list already indexed" as if trying to recreated and reindex at every run.
And when I change it to `false` it runs ok.

Should I determine if the tables are created in order to toggle the `UpdateSchema` property? Or I've configured the service wrong?

OracleDB is 19.17.0.0

.NET: 7

Nuggets:

- Hangfire: 1.8.5
- Hangfire.Core: 1.8.5
- Hangfire.FluentNHibernateStorage: 1.7.30
- Hangfire.Oracle.Core: 1.2.17
- FluentNHibernate: 3.3.0

Comment: I have the same problem, with UpdateSchema = true it doestn't run, with UpdateSchema = false it runs properly... did you solve the problem ?